# Minecraft/Bukkit - How does latency affect hit distances?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit, latency

On my adventure to try to make an anticheat plugin, I realize that I need a bit more knowledge having to do with latency and how the Minecraft client and server act. The current plugin I am developing is dealing with reach. One factor I must take into account is determining whether a far hit was due to lag or a client.

I've thought of a couple ways to detect lag/high ping to be sure that far hits are due to a client and not lag. My problem is, who has to be "lagging" for a far hit to occur do to lag? The person hitting; the person being hit; or the server?
When I say the server, will it make a difference if the host's internet is slowing down and the server program just running slow? Will that effect how the hits are registered (will that cause far hits)?

If it matters, my setup to determine distances between hits is just a `onPlayerHit` event handler:

```js
public void onPlayerHit(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) {

  // make sure they are all players
  if (!(event.getEntity() instanceof Player) | !(event.getDamager() instanceof Player))
    return;

  // get the event's players
  Player damaged = (Player) event.getEntity();
  Player damager = (Player) event.getDamager();

  // get the locations
  Location damagedLocation = damaged.getLocation();
  Location damagerLocation = damager.getLocation();

  // calculate the distance
  double distance = damagedLocation.distance(damagerLocation);

  // broadcast it to everyone
  for (Player p: Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', "&f" + damager.getDisplayName() + "&3 has just damaged &f" + damaged.getDisplayName() + "&3 from a distance of &4" + distance));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not ran any tests, or done that much research, but my intuition tells me that the player being hit is the only one that could cause a far hit to occur due to lag, here's why I think so:

- If the server were to lag, the players would still send the information at the exact same time, and when the server finally recieved it, it would be at the same time, and  therefore it would  not seem wrong
- If the player hitting were to lag, that would mean that he could hit the other player, with a distance (according to the players client) of only 3 blocks. The data is sent to the server, but the server realises that that player is too far away, so that hit is just not marked as a hit, and the event is never called.
- If the player being hit were to lag, that would make the server think he was at 3, 0, 0 even though he moved to 0, 0, 0. So let's say the player hitting is at 6, 0, 0, that would make the server think that the hit is alright (because it thinks the other player is at 3, 0, 0), but when it's about to send the information to your plugin, the player being hit finally gets his location updated, and then that location is sent to your plugin instead of the initial location that actually let the event be called.

Again, I haven't done much research, so this is just what I am thinking,  maybe I'm wrong, maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the following; the server, player hitting, or player damaged have latency, it will affect hit distances. I ran tests. Lots of tests.

Answer (score 0):

[image: server explenation]

Imagine a server who knows the coordinates of 2 players.
Example:

```
Plant A[0, 64, 0]  
Laptop User[5, 64, 0]
```

But when Plant A moves it takes a few milliseconds to say to the server 'Hey I moved 1 block to the north' And then it takes a few milliseconds again to say to Laptop User 'Hey, Plant A moved a little'.
Now you can imagine in your head what happens when Plant A has a slow connection, and what happens when Laptop User has a slow connection :)